# How to find and replace seemingly a tab char using sed?

Tags: sed, string, text-formatting, replace, whitespace

I have a line looks like this:

```
some.com    *.some.com
```

The space is seemingly a tab space because when I move the keyboard arrow, one move will move me to the end of it (it does not seem multiple spaces because multiple spaces will need me to move the keyboard arrow multiple times).

This space is causing me problems. I need to:

1. find what it is?
2. replace it with a single space.

How to do this? I have tried removing multiple spaces but this seems a single character that could not be removed.

**EDIT:**

Just additional info. the program that uses this line complains: `Invalid control character`

Comment: There is actually no indication that this tab character is the "invalid control character" that your program is complaining about. How do you know it is?

Answer (score 1):

It's a tab character.

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' <file >newfile
```

This would use `tr` to replace any tab or space in the file with a single space.  Multiple spaces in the output would be squeezed into single spaces. The result in written to `newfile`.

To just replace single tabs with single spaces, use

```
tr '\t' ' ' <file >newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

[show-special-characters-in-unix-while-using-less-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943928/show-special-characters-in-unix-while-using-less-command)

To see what that character is:

```
less -r sourcefile
```

or

```
od -c sourceFile
```

for a more verbose view.

[unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/)

To `sed` out the offending control code:

```
sed 's/'`echo "\033"`'/ /g'
```

where `\033` is replaced with whatever is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

you can eventually use this way too

```
sed -E "s,[[:space:]]+, ,g" /tmp/test
```

this will replace any single or multiple "white space" (space, tab) whith a single "space"

```
$ cat /tmp/test 
sdfsdfsdf    sdfsdfsdfsd
sdflksjdf    sdfélsdkfésldkf    ss
```

**result**

```
$ sed -E "s,[[:space:]]+, ,g" /tmp/test 
sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsd
sdflksjdf sdfélsdkfésldkf ss
```

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or a tab only, `[[:space:]]` matches a few more characters (newline, carriage-return, form-feed, vertical tab).